# how webGL works with Swing

Tags: swing, webgl

In my project the user can sketch a roof in 2d, and also can put antenna, chimney, water tank or cooler unit on the rooftop.

I need to do this usuing swing and webGL. Can anyone give me some idea or link so that I can proceed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Swing is a Java library. WebGL is a JavaScript library. Are you trying to mix both languages?

Comment: Possible to mix Java/Javascript? Short answer: No. Long Answer: Google Web Toolkit.

Answer (score 2):

## Just to clarify

[WebGL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebGL) is a JavaScript API bound to the language's Canvas API used to render high-performance 3D (and 2D) graphics with the computer's graphics card OpenGL implementation.

[Swing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swing_(Java)) is Java's GUI (inherited from Java's AWT) that comes shipped with its Standard Development Kit.

If you haven't noticed, that's 2 concepts in 2 different programming languages!

## Solving the problem

When I wanted to create a general game with Swing and I needed some rendered graphics, I would turn to [JOGL](http://jogamp.org/jogl/www/). It's an amazing library that couples nicely with some known GUI Toolkits in Java, such as (You guessed it!) Swing. You might want to use its `GLCanvas` and embed it into your `JFrame` directly. For some base code, check out:

- https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jogl/jogl_canvas_with_swing.htm
- https://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/Using_JOGL_in_AWT_SWT_and_Swing#JOGL_in_Swing

Now, you might need to consider migrating your JavaScript code to Java...